# Add header values to tile requests

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Is there any way to add header values to tile requests in ArcGIS 4.9. I'm using `WebTileLayer` and the tile server I'm connecting to uses Azure Active Directory authentication which requires passing in details in the header of each tile request.

I've tried using an interceptor

```
esriConfig.request.interceptors = [{
    urls: [/atlas.microsoft.com/],
    before: async function (params) {
        params.requestOptions.headers = {
            'x-ms-client-id': clientId,
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        };
    }
}];
```

I also tried:

```
esriConfig.request.interceptors.push({
    urls: [/atlas.microsoft.com/],
    authMode: 'anonymous',
    headers: {
        'x-ms-client-id': clientId,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
});
```

but the header values are never added to the tile requests.

Comment: I managed to get the `before` callback to fire by moving to v4.9 of ArcGIS and using a regular expression for the URL instead of a string. However, the headers don't appear to be attached to the tile requests.

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out. In versions 4.9 and below of ArcGIS JavaScript API, headers are ignored on image requests. This was fixed in version 4.10.

In my case the following added the headers I needed to tile requests once I pointed to version 4.10:

```
esriConfig.request.interceptors.push({
    urls: [/atlas.microsoft.com/],
    headers: {
        'x-ms-client-id': clientId,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
});
```